# Prevent jQuery Mobile from caching pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, mobile

Consider a page1.php file with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['var'])) unset($_SESSION['var']);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['var']; ?>
            <a href="page2.php">next page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a page2.php with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var']++;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['var']; ?>
            <a href="page1.php">previous page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I'm trying to get is when you click the link to go to page2.php, and then refresh the page a few times while on page2.php, and then click the link to go to page1.php, and then click the link again to go to page2.php, the counter should go back to the beginning. So basically, going to page1.php resets the counter and going to page2.php increments it.

However, what actually happens is I go to page2.php and refresh it a few times and the counter goes up like it should, then when I go back to page1.php and return to page2.php, the counter remains the same. But when I refresh the page now, it does go back to the beginning. So obviously the session variables are working and are being set and unset properly, but it seems like jQuery is caching the pages. Which doesn't really make sense either, because the data-dom-cache (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html) attribute is set to false by default. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add this to page2.php to get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('pagehide', 'div', function (event, ui) { 
    var page = jQuery(event.target);
    if (page.attr('data-cache') == 'never') { 
        page.remove(); 
    }; 
});
</script>
```

And also change `<div data-role="page">` to `<div data-role="page" data-cache="never">`